# tablesorter not coping with rowspan

Tags: html, sorting, knockout.js, grouping, tablesorter

I'm trying to sort a very simple HTML table using tablesorter and it's partially working but it seems to come unstuck with rowspans. Using the example, if I were to click on the sort, the columns would sort in group order (gender, age and height) and remain together. I.e. Male and Female rows would swap based on their count values and the other 2 rows of age and height would stay in the same place. Is this possible to do with tablesorter. Their example seem to be a lot more complex.

Any help would be great, thanks.

-- Example of table

```
<table style="border: solid 1px blue; width: 200px;" data-bind="sortTable: true">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>group</th>
                    <th>sort</th>
                    <th>Count</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2">Gender</td>
                    <td>Male</td>
                    <td>12</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Female</td>
                    <td>45</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Age</td>
                    <td>Yrs</td>
                    <td>24</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Height</td>
                    <td>Ft</td>
                    <td>23</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

ko.bindingHandlers.sortTable = {
                init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(element).tablesorter({
                            sortList: [[1, 1]]
                        });
                    }, 0);
                }
            };
```

Comment: Tablesorter does not yet support `colspan` or `rowspan` attributes within the tbody ([ref](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/485)); I'm not sure if there is a table sorting plugin that does.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll do some more research/messing around.